# PHP, DOMElement get value only current node

Tags: php, html, domdocument

**This is my code:**

```
<?php

$html = '<a href="url">My Asked text for value <span class="time">15min</span></a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link){print_r($link);
         echo $link->nodeValue."\n"; // returns: My Asked text for value 15min
}
```

It returns: **My Asked text for value 15min**

But i want only:  **My Asked text for value**

How to fix this, thx

Comment: please check this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c187f4686678eb32e15a314e07d5b18334b4a37d play around with the PHP version and check the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure that is possible using the parser methods:

```
<?php
$html = '<a href="url">My Asked text for value <span class="time">15min</span></a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link){
    if ($link->hasChildNodes()) {
        echo $link->childNodes[0]->nodeValue;
    } else {
        echo $link->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

The output obviously is:

```
My Asked text for value
```

It is questionable however if that makes sense, the rule *which* child to use appears a bit fuzzy...

---

UPDATE:

For outdated php versions < 5.6.3 you need a slightly modified version, since the class `DomNodeList` only implements the `ArrayAccess` Interface from that version upwards:

```
<?php
$html = '<a href="url">My Asked text for value <span class="time">15min</span></a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link){
    if ($link->hasChildNodes()) {
        echo $link->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    } else {
        echo $link->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Comment: @Nabi Ah, that means you have a really outdated php version, I will look for a work around...

Comment: @Nabi OK, I posted a work around that should also work for older php versions.

Comment: @arkascha check this out... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c187f4686678eb32e15a314e07d5b18334b4a37d play with the php version select-box and execute the code. Which code part does not give error on lower versions of PHP? The second snippet works fine with all PHP versions (tested up to version 7.1). The first snippet works fine on versions > 5.6.3. Therefor this is an edit proposal. I think correcting this in your answer would make it more valid.

Comment: @PeterDarmis I can't really see your point. Yes, the first version only works from version 5.6.3 upwards, the second version always works. That is what I already said. So what is your proposal? To _only_ offer the second version? I strongly disagree to that: that is the often seen habit never to use any new features for the sake of backwards compatibility. Why should one do that? The first version is much more elegant and I see little motivation in supporting outdated php versions...

Comment: @arkascha You wrote a thorough answer but the issue is just on presentation... The 1st part works only on updated PHP versions,yes it is more "elegant" since  it is more efficient by using "less coding" for getting the same result `childNodes[0]` against `childNodes->item(0)`. The second part is not a way to check the PHP version so the `For outdated php versions < 5.6.3` part is not correct.

Comment: @PeterDarmis So you want to change that statement "For outdated php versions < 5.6.3" to something like "works with _all_ php versions"? Sure, possible, but again: _why_? I recommend _not_ to use that version if you have a setup that is _not_ outdated. So the first version for php>=x.x.x and the second version for php<x.x.x. Still sounds legit to me...

Comment: @arkascha explaining better my thought... the second part works across all PHP versions that is a fact so it is for sure not outdated. But for best and more "byte efficient" coding the 1st code snippet is better. I used the words "byte-efficient" since all coding languages are de-compiled to `0` and `1` bottom line...

Comment: @PeterDarmis It is the php version that is outdated, not the code snippet. Outdated php versions should 1. be called like that and 2. not be used any more. I definitely think it makes sense to point that out. Apart from that the first version is preferable not due to "byte-efficiency", but simply because it is easier to read and understand. That is a top goal in programming to keep code maintainable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132267/discussion-between-peter-darmis-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 1):

Just change this code line:

```
echo $link->nodeValue."\n";
```

With this one:

```
echo $link->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";
// output "My Asked text for value"
```

check it in this [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03c538ec94830b6a0e154fc11e21a99b7299c996)

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace method. Or if the string every time new "15Min or 20Min" then u can use Regex for it :)

[str-replace here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php)

or regex [preq_match](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php)

```
  $newString = str_replace("15min", "", $link->nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a long way to go about it, but you could just strip out the  tag.

```
echo strip_tags($link->nodeValue."\n");
```

Comment: I have any tags in my nodeValue